# SwiftUI: ToggleStyle not working with @Binding

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to use the ToggleStyle with custom icons. Clicking on the toggle nothing happens, while if I disable the .toggleStyle part everything works correctly.
Can you help me?

```
import SwiftUI

public struct IconToggle: View {
  let onIcon: Image
  let offIcon: Image
  @Binding var isOn: Bool

  public init(
    onIcon: Image,
    offIcon: Image,
    isOn: Binding<Bool>
  ) {
    self.onIcon = onIcon
    self.offIcon = offIcon
    self._isOn = isOn
  }

  public var body: some View {
    Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
    }
      .toggleStyle(
        CheckboxStyle(
          onIcon: onIcon,
          offIcon: offIcon
        )
      )
  }
}


private struct CheckboxStyle: ToggleStyle {
  
  let onIcon: Image
  let offIcon: Image
  
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    (configuration.isOn ? onIcon : offIcon)
      .resizable()
      .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
      .onTapGesture {
        configuration.isOn.toggle()
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you want to make a custom Toggle() where the Image will switches every time you press the button. You can try my code below. A bit different in code, but logic is there.

```
import SwiftUI

//copy paste all of these and test it out
//just replace "apple" and "swift with your own image's name in the Assets Folder
//when you call IconToggle() view, there is no extra parameter, so this code will instantly run in your xcode

public struct IconToggle: View {

@State var isOn = true

public var body: some View {
    Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
    }
    .toggleStyle(
        CheckboxStyle(
        isOn: $isOn
        )
    )
}
}

private struct CheckboxStyle: ToggleStyle {

@Binding var isOn: Bool

func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    Image(isOn ? "apple" : "swift") //custom images in my laptop
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
        .onTapGesture {
            configuration.isOn.toggle()
        }
        .mask(Circle())
}
}
```